# Numpy Matmul causes error saying module has no attribute matmul

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to programming and was attempting to use numpy to multiply two matrices together. When I try to run the code

```
import numpy 

A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
B = numpy.array([4, 5, 6])

print(numpy.matmul(A, B))
```

I get an error that says

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'
```

Thanks for help in advance

Edit:
Just adding for context that when I run the same code in a jupyter notebook it runs correctly.

Comment: what's the output of `numpy.__version__`?

Comment: @MaxPower when I tested in terminal it outputed 1.17.2, but in the text editor that I was using, Atom, it output 1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

The [`numpy.matmul()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) function was only introduced in numpy 1.10.0, and from the comments it seems your version is older than that.

In older versions of numpy, you can use [`numpy.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot) for matrix multiplication, it will behave the same as `matmul()` when given two 2-D matrices.

Comment: How would I update numpy to gain support for the matmul function? Edit: It appears that in terminal it says I have numpy 1.17, but in Atom, the text editor I was using, it said I have version 1.8

Comment: if you're using pip: pip install numpy --upgrade otherwise if using anaconda (a popular package manager and virtual environment tool): conda install numpy=1.10.0